# Is there any payment gateway focusing India?

Tags: android, payment-gateway, credit-card

I was searching for a payment gateway for my application to integrate. MY application is much designed for India so i need to give debit and credit sale of payment process to the users.

I made a try with PayPal Express Checkout but it supports only PayPal account and credit card.

Is there any gateway for android.
Please share your info.

Comment: Interested in that myself.  Hope someone responds.

Comment: Is that possible to add dynamic billing items with google In app billing in android.

Comment: Why is the question closed, asking for a PG that works with android is a proper question! What would make a proper question to get PG options that work well with android?

Answer (score 4):

CCAvenue is pretty widely used here. Check them out at their website:

http://www.ccavenue.com/ccavenue_index.jsp

Comment: but do they have SDK for android?

Comment: no they have sdk's for web. You can easily integrate it using webviews or rest API calls I'm sure

Comment: can u explain some clearly please i need to integrate in to android app for online sales

Answer (score 2):

You can try [zooz](http://www.zooz.com/). 
Now even Google has allowed [merchant accounts in India](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/10/google-play-seller-support-in-india.htm)

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/index.html

Comment: the blog seems removed from android developer